# Why does the first slide in my carousel only display 3 items when the rest display 4?

Tags: php, jquery, carousel

So I have a carousel and I am displaying 4 items per slide, only problem is the first slide only displays 3. Anyone have an idea as to why it is only displaying 3 instead of 4 in the first one. Appreciate the help, thanks.

```
$counter = 1;
if($photo->rowCount() > 0){
    echo'
     <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carouselEditor">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
    ';

    foreach($photoSelect as $row){  
        if($counter % 4 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div class="item">';
        }                                                           
        echo'<div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><a class="thumbnail"><img src="'.$row['photo'].'" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a></div>';
        $counter++;
    }
    echo'</div>';
    echo'</div><!--.carousel-inner-->                                                               
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control carouselControlProfile">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control carouselControlProfile">›</a>
        </div><!--.Carousel-->      
    ';
}
```

Here is the page source printout of what is being displayed

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carouselEditor">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
         <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="1"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/abstract02.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="2"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/abstract03.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"> 
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="3"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/butterfly01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"> 
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="4"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/cartoon01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"> 
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="5"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/cartoon02.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"> 
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="6"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/desert01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"> 
           <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="7"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/leaf01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
         <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="8"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/rain01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
         <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="9"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/rosepetals01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
         <a class="thumbnail photoDisplay" data-photoDisplay-id="10"><img src="img/ProfileBackgrounds/sunset01.jpg" alt="Backgrounds" style="height:50px;width:75px;"></a>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div><!--.carousel-inner-->                                                              
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control carouselControlProfile">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control carouselControlProfile">›</a>
    </div><!--.Carousel-->
```

Comment: Might be because of `$counter = 1;`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the reply, I tried changing the counter to 0 and others but that won't work.

Comment: @Stuckfornow, please give us the processed code from the **Page Source** on your browser

Comment: `$counter` to 0 should work. Try to put your `echo` before your `if` in the `foreach`.